# Bootstrap datetimepicker not firing when inside Boostrap Collapse

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to put a bootstrap datetimerpicker inside of a bootstrap collapse, but when I click on the glyphcon, the calander does not dropdown. I assume that there is some javascript conflict that is preventing the dropdown of the calander where the user can pick a date.

Here is the code:

```
        <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Request Pickup</h4>
                </div>
              </a>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <h4>Selected A Date</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="delivery_time" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                                  format: "dd MM yyyy - HH:ii P",
                                  showMeridian: true,
                                  autoclose: true,
                                  todayBtn: false
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using rails with this [gem](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails) which works perfectly when not in a collapse. Any help or critiques are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you either provided an incorrect link, or may be referring to the incorrect documentation; as most options you are using are not part of the datetimepicker in question http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

It's hard to tell what format you are trying to use for your date, as you are not using valid moment format(s) http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

You will also likely need to add some custom CSS to allow for `overflow: visible;` on Bootstrap panels.

Provided we are talking about the right datetimepicker, something like this should get you going. You will have to play with the moment formats to suit your needs.

**See Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/spasticdonkey/6g7j55f2/3/

```
$(function () {
    $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
        format: "DD MM YYYY - HH:mm Z",
        useCurrent: false
    });
});
```

Comment: This helped turns out another date picker with the same id was already on the page in another modal in a partial. Changing the Id to a new one worked. Dumb mistake